# shell code to check if a website up or down. but keep gives an error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

what's wrong with code, i keep getting an error running it.
this is the error:
**updown.sh: **line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
updown.sh: line 10: conditional binary operator expected
updown.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file****

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter the site:"
read site_url
if [[ 'ping -w 100 -c 1 "$site_url"|tail -2|head
-1|cut -d , -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f2` > 0 ]]; then
        echo "site is up"
else
        echo "site is down"
fi
```

updown.sh: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
updown.sh: line 10: conditional binary operator expected
updown.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: You have a plain quote instead of a backtick in `if [[ 'ping`. This confusion is one of the reasons [`$( )` is preferred over backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will have several other good suggestions; I recommend running your script past it and fixing everything it points out.

Comment: Why not simply `if ping -c1 "$site_url"; then # do something; done` There is no need to use `[[ ... ]]` as `ping` returns success or failure on exit. If you want to negate the test and do something if the ping fails, then `if ! ping -c1 "$site_url"; ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter the site:"
read -r site_url
if [ "$(ping -w 100 -c 1 "$site_url" | tail -2| head -1 |cut -d , -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f2)" -gt 0 ]
then
        echo "site is up"
else
        echo "site is down"
fi
```

Comment: i got this 'updown.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file'

Comment: you can use `shellcheck` to check the format of shell
https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck#on-the-web

Comment: This works like a charm on my shell..

Answer (score 1):

Seems overwrought to me. How about just

```
if ping -w 100 -c 1 "$site_url" # is ping really what you want here?
```

or maybe (as an example to elaborate as needed, assigning on the fly here...)

```
curl -sI "$site_url" |
  awk '/^HTTP/{
       switch(int($2/100)) {
         case 1: msg="Informational"             ; break;
         case 2: msg="Site is up"                ; break;
         case 3: msg="Redirect"                  ; break;
         case 4: print "Client Error " $2        ; exit 4;
         case 5: print "Server Error " $2        ; exit 5;
         default: print "Unexpected error - " $0 ; exit 6;
       }
       print msg " ("$2")"; exit;
   } END { print "Site error, no code"           ; exit 7; }'
```

Which, using `site_url=https://google.com`, gives

```
Redirect (301)
```

Manually passing a fail:

```
echo "HTTP/2 444" | awk '/^HTTP/{ switch(int($2/100)) {
  case 1: msg="Informational" ; break;
  case 2: msg="Site is up"    ; break;
  case 3: msg="Redirect"      ; break;
  case 4: print "Client Error " $2 ; exit 4;
  case 5: print "Server Error " $2 ; exit 5;
  default: print "Unexpected error - " $0; exit 6;
  } print msg " ("$2")"; exit; } END { print "Site error, no code"; exit 7; }'
Client Error 444
```

If for some reason you just need it to still be part of an `if` test -

```
if curl -sI ${site_url:=https://google.com} |
     awk '/^HTTP/{
       switch(int($2/100)) {
         case 1: msg="Informational" ; break;
         case 2: msg="Site is up"    ; break;
         case 3: msg="Redirect"      ; break;
         case 4: print "Client Error " $2 ; exit 4;
         case 5: print "Server Error " $2 ; exit 5;
         default: print "Unexpected error - " $0; exit 6;
       }
       print msg " ("$2")"; exit;
     } END { print "Site error, no code"; exit 7; }'
then echo doing some other stuff
else echo doing error stuff
fi
```

which gives

```
Redirect (301)
doing some other stuff
```

Or

```
if curl -sI some.broken.site | awk '/^HTTP/{ switch(int($2/100)) {
   case 1: msg="Informational" ; break;
   case 2: msg="Site is up"    ; break;
   case 3: msg="Redirect"      ; break;
   case 4: print "Client Error " $2 ; exit 4;
   case 5: print "Server Error " $2 ; exit 5;
   default: print "Unexpected error - " $0; exit 6;
   } print msg " ("$2")"; exit; } END { print "Site error, no code"; exit 7; }';
then echo doing some other stuff; else echo doing error stuff; fi
```

for

```
Site error, no code
doing error stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace with this line

```
if [[ `ping -W 100 -c 1 "$site_url"|tail -2|head -1|cut -d , -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f2` > 0 ]]; then
```

First issue; opening quote of in front of ping.
I think it should be a capital W option for ping

Comment: capital W for Mac, I could not try in a linux machine. May be small w is still valid. In that case it was just the quote issue.